# What is the maximum distance for a Wi-FI repeater?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, home-networking

I have a problem that even though it's simple, it might help a lot of people.

I have a 200mb/s internet, it is in house A. I want to take this connection to house B. Which is approximately 110 meters from A.

I currently use a router (D-Link DIR-815) that is connected via cable to ONT in house A. And a router (TP-LINK TL-WR841HP) in repeater mode in house B.

In house B on sunny days, the speed reaches 15mb/s. And it has 5 wifi cameras connected there.

Now comes the problem: On rainy/cold/foggy days, the quality and stability of the signal is horrible. I would like to know if there are ways I can improve this.

Possible solutions that I've been finding, but I'm not sure if they will work:

- Cable from house A to B, and in the middle of the way put a router, because according to the standard a network cable would have to be a maximum of 100m, so I have to have two cables of 55 with a router in the middle.
- Place the router in house A in a high place, and outside the house.

If you have any other suggestions for a solution, you are most welcome.

Obs: My objective is not to take 200mb/s in the house B. And yes to improve the stability.

Thanks.

Comment: The distance is long for consumer gear which is what you have. Maybe get a good consultant contractor in to see if commercial gear will help or whether there is a better solution for you. It likely will not be cheap for this distance.

Comment: You are not going to want a repeater rather a point to point solution.  Ubiquity has some prosumer gear that will fit the bill.  Hop over to their forums and post your requirements there. https://community.ui.com/questions

Comment: Setup directional wifi antennas. We have 600 meters with cheap dlink more then 10 years ago

Comment: Cable will beat everything when it comes to reliability. You don't even need a router in the middle - just a switch will do.

Comment: Can you edit the question as I don't think the title matches the actual question

Comment: @John Deploying commercial gear IMO is quite an overkill, and the cost by far outweighs the benefits. There are much cheaper solutions to solve the problem which require much less effort and cost.

Answer (score 1):

If it is a long term install, then put in a fibre link.
Use two Fibre / Ethernet Media Converters (e.g. TP-Link single mode) and run an optical fibre between the houses.

Make sure the Media Converter speeds matches your internal networking speed (e.g. Gigabit) as they typically don't automatically adjust their speeds.

Comment: What's the advantage of fiber over copper?

Comment: The problem is, where is the optical fiber to be left? You'd have to deploy it somewhere...

Comment: @Robidu: Dig a trench, run the fiber (or copper) through some pipe from building A to B? I don't really see the problem.

Comment: @user1686 Right. Why do it the easy way when you can make things way more complicated...

Comment: Stability & capacity of cable connection (copper or fiber) is always going to be better than long distance Wifi. Especially in a build up area with many other Wifi networks nearby. If it was ethernet, then a powered router would probably be required between the buildings. There probably isn't any power available in that location? But I guess PoE could be used to fix this, if a water proof enclosure is available. Fibre is also better if water gets in the cable. If you are going to dig a trench then may as well future proof it. Those 5 cameras might get upgraded to 8K in a few years.

Answer (score 1):

A possible setup to get and retain a stable connection is using directional antennas. You simply replace the omnidirectional antenna with a long Yagi (they are available for Wifi bands) on both sides.

Since TX power for Wifi NICs is limited, that has to be compensated somehow. A directional antenna has high gain in its primary direction (a Yagi consisting of 8 elements grants ~10 dBd), which should easily suffice to bridge the gap (it doesn't just boost your TX but your RX as well). In case you are still experiencing problems you can also insert an amplifier between your Wifi NIC and the Yagi, boosting your TX power even further.

However, when setting this up, you need to make sure that the Yagi matches the band that you are intending to use, because if it doesn't, the quality of your connection is going to deteriorate (misaligned frequency changing the antenna's impedance, and that is going to cause part of the outbound signal to be reflected back to your NIC).

On the upside the directional antennas take care of transmitting the signal to where you intend so it doesn't interfere with stations in the neighborhood. It also spares you the hassle with deploying cabling or intermediate stations.